# Proof a subset is valid

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

No answers, please, hints only.

---

Given that $A=\{p+q\sqrt2: p,q\text{ are rational}\}, B=\{r+s\sqrt3: r, s\text{ are rational}\}, Q=\mathbb{Q}$.
Show that $Q\subseteq A\cap B$.

---

I tried using a direct proof. I have a feeling that since $\sqrt2, \sqrt3$ are irrational then $A$ and $B$ cannot be rational, so their intersections cannot contain the elements of $Q$, but I'm not getting anywhere with this

Comment: If you mean $Q=\Bbb Q$, then take $q=s=0$. If $Q=\{\Bbb Q\}$ maybe it does not make sense...

Comment: Oh i didn't know there was a difference. Could you explain the difference when there's brackets and when there isnt?

Comment: $Q=\Bbb Q$ means that bioth sets are the same. $Q=\{\Bbb Q\}$ means that $Q$ is the set whose unique element is $\Bbb Q$. Is the same difference between $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$.

Comment: So for the inclusion, as it stays now, $\Bbb Q\subseteq A\cap B$, just show $\Bbb Q\subseteq A$ and $\Bbb Q\subseteq B$. There is a further hint, "$A$ and $B$ cannot be rational" makes no sense. $A$ is a set, there is no terminology i know of calling a set rational. "Their intersection**s**" with what? Please take some time to write down a clear question. Then show the own attempts to solve the issue.

Comment: If at least I can understand what you even mean, consider the fact that  $A = \{p+q\sqrt{2}: p,q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ is the extension  $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. Same thing goes for $B$, so you can see it is $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$. Since $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]\neq\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$, well then their only intersection is $\mathbb{Q}$. Obviously, it is $q=s=0$...

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*- $\mathbb Q\subset A$ and $\mathbb Q\subset B$ so that $A\cap B=...$